# How I can avoid RouterLink removing trailing backslash

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am having following HTML component, for a URL navigation:

```
       <a routerLink='/home/@latest/{{item}}'>{{item}}</a>
```

Even if the value of item is `"test_page/"`, it removes trailing backslach and it gets translated to:

`<a href="/home/@latest/test_page">`.

But I want the trailing backslash to stay.

If I use, href instead of routerLink in html, it works well but it loads entire page.

Can anyone please help me how I can fix this. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: may I know why you need the trailing backslash?

Comment: Based on the backslash, my application decides if we need to open a directory or file. (File will not have backslash)

Comment: Why don't you use a route parameter for this? e.g. `/home/@latest/{{item}}/directory`

Comment: my application expects URL to be /home/@latest/dir_name/ so that it knows, this is a folder.

Comment: Seems like there are better ways to do this than relying on a backslash. IE directory links all look like ‘/:dirName/list’ whereas “files” omit the /list segment?

Comment: This is the current implementation and so I am trying to avoid touching this.

Comment: we generally use `routerLink` for routing...so to switch between components and such...if your app does something to the files which are not components then shouldn't you use the click event and pass the URL as a param and do what your app does with the URL in a function which gets called on click?

Comment: A bad current implementation is no reason to keep doing things poorly

Comment: You might need to use PathLocationStrategy , ,have a look 
 https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy

Comment: @undefined do you have routes with paths like `/home/@latest/someItem` in your routing module?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this by putting the / in the end :

```
<a routerLink='/home/@latest/{{item}}/'>{{item}}</a>
```